# How on init make a POST call based on model resolve

Tags: ember.js

i am newbie in ember and need your help.

In the application/route.js I need to make a POST call based on response that model gets. Something like this in route.js:

```
export default Route.extend({
  ajax: inject.service(),
  details: inject.service(),

  model() {
      return this.get('details').fetchAccount();
  },
```

so once model gets resolved on init I will need to make a call. The model has status, which run a call if it is true.

```
init() {
    if (model.user) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Any thoughts how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `this.get('details').fetchAccount()` is not returning Promise then you can try using `setupController` hook.

```
setupController(controller,model){
 this._super(...arguments);
 if (model.user) {
       ...
    }
}
```

It's all depends on the what are you going to after model resolved, are you going to set any properties to controller then you can make use of the setupController hook.

Comment: No setup on controller. After it get resolved I need to run if it is true run POST call.

Comment: You can try run POST call in `if` block.

Answer (score 1):

You can instruct the `model` method what to do when the `fetchAccount` method's promise resolves:

```
model() {
  let fetchedAccount = this.get('details').fetchAccount();

  fetchedAccount.then(account => {
    doTheThingWith(account); // Obviously, your own code here
  });

  return fetchedAccount;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! Let me try that.

Comment: Hi Chris, I am getting error. TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function properties and cannot be accessed in this context.
I was trying to do this.
      fetchedAccount.then(account => {
           console.log(account);
      });

Comment: I'm not sure that I'll be able to help you, but you may want to consider updating your question with the code from `fetchAccount()` so that someone else can help you. My main experience is with using Ember Data, not rolling my own Promise structure.

Comment: Fairenough! Thank you Chris!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `afterModel` hook of route.

Comment: I do not use ember-data. I am not sure if it is going to work but thanks for comment.

Comment: You can use it even you are not using ember-data. We are not using ember-data too :) If `fetchAccount()` returns a promise, after promise resolved `afterModel` hook of route will be executed.